# Unable to fetch NSData from URL objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Following [this tutorial](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/basic-json-parsing-in-ios/) I wrotte this code:

```
NSData* json = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.fessor.da.stanids.office/homework/index/?rp[token]=app&rp[workspace]=parent&child_id=22066&type=parent&start_date=2014-05-01&end_date=2014-05-01"]];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",json]);
```

But i get nil when i log the result.
Can anybody tell me if this tutorial is simply bad or I am doing something wrong somewhere?

P.S. I am calling this code in viewDidLoad.

Comment: First try executing your request in the browser. It is not working in browser as well, so it is not working in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your url is not available or something wrong. Try to use another url like : http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/programmes/schedules/fm/today.json

It should work.

Comment: You're right. This link only worked when connected to internal network.
I should have checked that before

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData* json = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.fessor.da.stanids.office/homework/index/?rp[token]=app&rp[workspace]=parent&child_id=22066&type=parent&start_date=2014-05-01&end_date=2014-05-01"]];

NSDictionary * dictData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Try with this..